# request.auth is null in Firestore rules when use Emulator

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, emulation

I'm working on testing Firestore rules via `AngularFire` and `Firebase Emulators`.
My `firestore rule` is very simple and only checks whether the user logged in or not.
And what problem is that it isn't allowed any user reaches the `Firestore`, despite the user is after authed.

But when I don't use Emulator(i.e. use real Firestore ), it is allowed.

So I wonder whether there are additional settings when I use Emulator?
Please help me!

**Browser console:**

```
core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: PERMISSION_DENIED: 
false for 'create' @ L5
```

**My environment:**

- firebase-tools: 9.8.0
- Angular: 11.2.12
- @angular/fire: 6.1.4

**My Firestore rules:**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts:**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: USE_AUTH_EMULATOR, useValue: environment.useEmulators ? ['localhost', 9099] : undefined },
    { provide: USE_DATABASE_EMULATOR, useValue: environment.useEmulators ? ['localhost', 9000] : undefined },
    { provide: USE_FIRESTORE_EMULATOR, useValue: environment.useEmulators ? ['localhost', 8080] : undefined },

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html:**

```html
<button (click)="onLoginButtonClick()">change status(current: {{status}})</button><br>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```js
export class AppComponent {
  status = 'not logged in';
  
  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afStore: AngularFirestore
  ) {
    this.afAuth.authState
      .subscribe((user) => {
        if ( user != null ) {
          // If user logged in, then add new data.
          this.afStore
            .collection('test_data')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .set({data: 'test data'}); // this causes error!
        }
      });
  }
  async onLoginButtonClick(): Promise<void>{
    if ( this.status === 'not logged in'){
      const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);
      this.status = 'logged in';
    }
    else{
      await this.afAuth.signOut();
      this.status = 'not logged in';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: After this, I found this comment that is a solution for a problem a little like this. And when I tried to do that, I solved the problem that the comment mentioned, but my problem remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After all, I tried to upgrade `firebase-tools` and its version became 9.8 to 9.10, then my problem was fixed.
And I found this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3258), and it seemed like Firebase Emulator's issue.
Thanks.